# Is there a way to distinguish Long Text Area field or Rich Text Area field from a regular Text Area?

Tags: soql, fields, dynamic-soql, filters, where

I need to build an interface to allow a user to filter record by the field chosen by the user. I know that I can use `Text Area` fields in the `WHERE` Clause but I can't use  `Long Text Area` field or `Rich Text Area` field in the `WHERE` Clause.

When I try to read the field type describe for the field type, both fields return `DisplayType.TextArea`, so I can't distinguish them by simply executing the code

```
static Boolean canBeUsedInWhereClause(DescribeFieldResult fd) {
   return fd.getType() != DisplayType.TextArea;
}
```

since all of these

```
Opportunity.Test_Text_Area_Long__c.getDescribe().getType();
Opportunity.Test_Text_Area_Rich__c.getDescribe().getType();
Opportunity.Test_Text_Area__c.getDescribe().getType();
```

return the same value.

I could potentially use additional SOQL query to check if this fails or not

```
static Boolean canBeUsedInWhereClause(DescribeFieldResult fd) {

    try {
        List<SObject> records = Database.query('SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE ' + fd.getName() + ' = null');
        return true;
    } catch (System.QueryException e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

however, this looks ugly and I don't want to run an `SOQL` query only to find out if I can display the field in the list of field available for filtering.

Is there any other elegant way to find which field is available to be used in the `WHERE` clause? Is there any way to distinguish `Text Area` from `Long` or `Rich Text Area` other than checking if `SOQL` query raises an exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is method in the DescribeFieldResult to determine if the field can be used as part of the filter criteria of a WHERE statement, this method `isFilterable()` can be used to distinguish the field type

```
System.debug('@@@ field LONG ' + Opportunity.Test_Text_Area_Long__c.getDescribe().isFilterable() ); // False
System.debug('@@@ field Rich ' + Opportunity.Test_Text_Area_Rich__c.getDescribe().isFilterable()); // False
System.debug('@@@ field Text ' + Opportunity.Test_Text_Area__c.getDescribe().isFilterable()); // True
```

And the method to determine if field can be used in the `WHERE` clause may just call this method `isFilterable`

```
static Boolean canBeUsedInWhereClause(DescribeFieldResult fd) {
   return fd.isFilterable();
}
```

Update:

Found some additional way of distinction, it is possible to query the `ExtraTypeInfo` field on `FieldDefinition`:

```
SELECT DeveloperName, ExtraTypeInfo FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'Opportunity' AND DeveloperName LIKE 'Test_Text_Area%'
```

which can help to distinguish between `Rich` and `Long Text Area` fields

```
Test_Text_Area_Long plaintextarea   
Test_Text_Area_Rich richtextarea    
Test_Text_Area  plaintextarea
```

Comment: That's pretty clever, though I wish there was a more explicit property that describes RTAs vs plain text fields.

Comment: Agree. My initial thought was to check for isSortable() and this is how I implemented in the real project, but when I was preparing this post with answer I have double checked the documentation and figured out there is actually isFilterable() method which looks more appropriate for my case

Comment: @sfdcfox there is actually a property ExtraTypeInfo on FieldDefinition that describes RTAs vs plain text fields. however, it is not available through Field Describe

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method **isHtmlFormatted** to distinguish between the two

> isHtmlFormatted()
>
> Returns true if the field has been formatted for HTML and should be
> encoded for display in HTML, false otherwise. One example of a field
> that returns true for this method is a hyperlink custom formula field.
> Another example is a custom formula field that has an IMAGE text
> function.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_getType